# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception, jdbc

I am getting this exception from today onwards. Yesterday things were fine. I will post my code :

```
public void enterStaff() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?"
                        + "user=root&password=virus");
        statement = connect.createStatement();

        preparedStatement = connect
                .prepareStatement("SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema.tables\n"
                        + "WHERE table_schema = 'project' AND table_name = 'staff'");
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        int chk = rs.getInt(1);

        if (chk != 1) {
            preparedStatement = connect
                    .prepareStatement("create table staff (staffname varchar(30) primary key);");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }

        preparedStatement = connect
                .prepareStatement("insert into staff values(?);");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, addSubName.getText());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        close2();
    }

}

private void close2() {
    try {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (connect != null) {
            connect.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
}
```

I am trying to create a table with only one column and that column is the primary key. When the code is run for the first time the table is getting created. But value is not getting entered. No exception is shown then. But when I try to enter value for the second time, the exception comes up.

How can I correct this ? If anyone needs to see some more code I will post it.

This is the code through which the user enters the data :

```
    addSubName = new TextField();
    addSubName.setPromptText("Staff Name");
    addSubName.setPrefSize(200, 30);

    final Button b2 = new Button("Add");
    b2.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 17));
    b2.setPrefSize(70, 30);
    b2.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066ff;");
    b2.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
    b2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

            data.add(new Staff(addSubName.getText()));
            addSubName.clear();

            try {
                enterStaff();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AddStaff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AddStaff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

The exception details is :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at addstaff.AddStaff.enterStaff(AddStaff.java:149)
at addstaff.AddStaff$2.handle(AddStaff.java:100)
at addstaff.AddStaff$2.handle(AddStaff.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6867)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3311)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3151)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3106)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2248)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Can we see the values you're inserting? Your create statement's got no auto_increment or anything of the sort, so maybe the insert values are messing up.

Comment: @d_ominic What should I post ?

Comment: Some example insert values, or the code that generates/determines the values you're putting in the insert statement.

Comment: The value you tried to submit through the text box must already be present in the table. You might have clicked `Add` button more than once.

Comment: No I pressed the button only once. Am sure about that.

Comment: paste the stacktrace here

Comment: @jmail I pasted it. Have a look and help me.

Comment: @jmail What you mean ?

Comment: Try to run your SQL statements outside of your code.

Answer (score 1):

*you shoud `remove` the `;` in your sql query:*

***wrong query:***

```
prepareStatement("create table staff (staffname varchar(30) primary key);");

preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("insert into staff values(?);");
```

***correct query is:***

```
prepareStatement("create table staff (staffname varchar(30) primary key)");

preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("insert into staff values(?)");
```

***CHECK YOUR INSERT QUERY***

*And, I think your **INSERT** the values in the db, that query is too wrong, did mention the **tablename** only, you should not mention the **columnname**. so you should must add the tablename with your query.*

***wrong query:***

```
insert into staff values(?)
```

***correct query:***

```
    INSERT INTO table_name
    VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

---

***refer this link:***

**http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp**

***UPDATE:1***

***wrong code:***

```
statement = connect.createStatement();
preparedStatement = connect
                .prepareStatement("SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema.tables\n"
                        + "WHERE table_schema = 'project' AND table_name = 'staff'");
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
```

***you should change like:sample***

```
Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName,user,password);
st = con.createStatement();
String sql="SELECT * FROM employees";
rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
```

*Note:*

1. *you should not call the sql query.*
2. *And, you are using `preparedStatement` to call, you should must chage to `statement`*
3. *the `preparedStatement` is can't resolved.*

*like,*

```
string sql=....sql query...;
statement.executeQuery(sql)
```

***update:2:-->sample***

```
public class User 
{
private String empname;
public String getEmpName()
{
    return empname;
}
public void setEmpName(String empname)
{
    this.empname=empname;
}
```

---

```
public void addUser(User user)
{
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ps=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee (empname,empaddress,depname) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, user.getEmpName());
        ps.setString(2, user.getEmpAddress());
        ps.setString(3, user.getDepName());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tom, check this ansswer

Comment: It doesn't worked. Did you noticed the exception ? It says duplicate value for primary key. The exception is coming at the second time of entry, not at the first time. That means the data is not getting entered into the database. Why data is not getting entered into the database ?

Comment: In the 'b2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() ' I first wrote the ' addSubName.clear(); '. Then I wrote the ' enterStaff() ' method. So automatically it will get an empty value at the time of insertion to the table in the database. So I called ' enterStaff() ' method first and then called ' addSubName.clear() ' method. But this too don't worked.

Comment: How can I change this -  preparedStatement.setString(1, msg);

Comment: Which part in that referred question is helpful to me ?

Comment: you are asking like `How can I change this - preparedStatement.setString(1, msg);`

Comment: What is this 'user' in user.getEmpName() ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow it. Can you tell me your email, I will post the entire code to you.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause for this error is that you are trying to enter the same value on a primary key filed into a table.

For example if you have a table `users` where the primary key is `user_id` and you try to entry the following:

```
INSERT INTO users ('user_id', 'name', 'age') VALUES (112233, 'Tom', 18);
INSERT INTO users ('user_id', 'name', 'age') VALUES (112233, 'Barry', 21);
```

A `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry` error will arise.

Note: there could be certain valid cases where one needs to insert or update a column in the a table and in such cases one can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO social_link ('user_id', 'social_id') VALUES (112233, 59874) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE social_id=575123;
```