# Alternative for " preparedStatement.setString(1, msg); "

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Am in an attempt to insert some data from a user form to MySQL. It contains some simple steps.
Read a value from a TextField and insert it into a table. My code is :

```
public void enterStaff() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connect = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?"
                    + "user=root&password=virus");
    statement = connect.createStatement();

    preparedStatement = connect
            .prepareStatement("SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema.tables\n"
                    + "WHERE table_schema = 'project' AND table_name = 'staff'");
    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    int chk = rs.getInt(1);

    if (chk != 1) {
        preparedStatement = connect
                .prepareStatement("create table staff (staffname varchar(30) primary key);");
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }

    preparedStatement = connect
            .prepareStatement("insert into staff values(?);");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, addSubName.getText());

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    close2();
}

}

private void close2() {
try {

    if (statement != null) {
        statement.close();
    }

    if (connect != null) {
        connect.close();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {

}
}
```

Unfortunately this code generated " com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' ". So I edited my code and it is :

```
public void enterStaff() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, 
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    String sql;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?"
                        + "user=root&password=virus");
        statement = connect.createStatement();

        sql = "SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema.tables "
                + "WHERE table_schema = 'project' AND table_name = 'staff'";

        rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        rs.next();
        int chk = rs.getInt(1);

        if (chk != 1) {
            sql="create table staff (staffname varchar(30) primary key)";
            rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        }

        sql="insert into staff values (?)";
        //preparedStatement.setString(1, msg); // ...HOW TO CHANGE IT ???

        rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        close2();
    }

}

private void close2() {
    try {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (connect != null) {
            connect.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
}
```

I changed most the code. But I don't know how to change " preparedStatement.setString(1, addSubName.getText()); ". How can I change it according to new code ?

Comment: It says you are trying to insert a duplicate primary key (probably the empty string from the looks of the message). Double-check what your variables contain.

Comment: @Thilo Yes, I know the empty string is the problem. Its been a long time that am trying to correct it. I asked a question before. Please look it-     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926420/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception-dupl