# Same type of codes, but one code shows exception

Tags: java, mysql, exception

I edited the question. This is the full code. Have a look at it.

```
  public class AddStaff extends Application {

    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    TextField addSubName;
    String msg;
    private TableView<Staff> table = new TableView<Staff>();
    private final ObservableList<Staff> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    final HBox hb = new HBox();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Add Staff");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        final Label label = new Label("Staff Details");
        label.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 22));
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        TableColumn sub = new TableColumn("Staff Name");
        sub.setMinWidth(400);
        sub.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Staff, String>("subName"));
        sub.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        sub.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Staff, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Staff, String> t) {
                        ((Staff) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setSubName(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(sub);
        addSubName = new TextField();
        addSubName.setPromptText("Staff Name");
        addSubName.setPrefSize(200, 30);    
        final Button b2 = new Button("Add");
        b2.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 17));
        b2.setPrefSize(70, 30);
        b2.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066ff;");
        b2.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        b2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                msg = addSubName.getText();
                try {
                    enterStaff();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AddStaff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                data.add(new Staff(addSubName.getText()));
                addSubName.clear();
            }
        });

        hb.getChildren().addAll(addSubName, b2);
        hb.setSpacing(5);
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);
        vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #333333;");
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void enterStaff() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?"
                            + "user=root&password=virus");
            statement = connect.createStatement();

            preparedStatement = connect
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema.tables\n"
                            + "WHERE table_schema = 'project' AND table_name = 'staff'");
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            int chk = rs.getInt(1);

            if (chk != 1) {
                preparedStatement = connect
                        .prepareStatement("create table staff (staffname varchar(30) primary key");
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }

            preparedStatement = connect
                    .prepareStatement("insert into staff values(?)");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, msg);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            close2();
        }

    }

    private void close2() {
        try {

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (connect != null) {
                connect.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

This code is producing an exception -

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I don't know why this exception occurs. Am trying a long time to correct it. How can I avoid that exception ?

I asked this before. Look that too-  [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926420/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception-dupl)

Comment: 1. `SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema` to `SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema`. 
2. staffname is primary key so make sure u do not add a duplicate value for it.

Comment: you can easily find the bug by debugging you code...seems like msg is not populated with the correct input.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's your code but you are trying to insert an entry with the same primary key to the database.

```
Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This means the item you're inserting has  `''` (null) as pirmary key and you have already inserted an item with this key.

The problem might be that you are creating the table but it is already there from the previous run. When you are creating a new table always try to `DROP` first.

Comment: Look at the exception once more. It says am trying to enter ' ' for more than one time. But I didn't tried to enter ' ' any time. Always I type some data in the text field. Some how the data in the text field is not getting entered into the database.

Comment: @Tom: It can be that from the previous run the table is there (you didn't drop it) with the previously inserted item.

Comment: @Tom: when you debug the msg variable value at the line "preparedStatement.setString(1, msg);" is it null? (you could either print it out with System.out.println(msg); to see). We could split the question here (is it DB related or is it input related).

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in code but you are inserting values in database which is violating primary key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

```
Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Clearly states you are trying to enter duplicate empaty String to Primary field `staffname`.

```
create table staff (staffname varchar(30) primary key
```

`stuffname` is field is primary key. I assume variable `msg` is an empty string and you have tried to run your code twice.

---

```
enterStaff(addSubName.getText());
```

...

```
public void enterStaff(String stuffName){
   if(stuffName!=null && !stuffName.trim().isEmpty()){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Look at the exception once more. It says am trying to enter ' ' for more than one time. But I didn't tried to enter ' ' any time. Always I type some data in the text field. Some how the data in the text field is not getting entered into the database.

Comment: debug the `msg` field. there might the main problem

Answer (score 1):

```
Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

exception says, You are trying to insert a value of primary key which is already present in table.

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, msg);
```

you are trying to insert `msg` which is `null` probably because exception says `Duplicate entry ''` in `staff` table, which is already present there and your column `staffname` is having primary key constraint so it will not allow you to insert duplicate values.

---

**Edit** :

Reason for exception is same after your edit.
However you can improve your code design.

Give msg as parameter of `enterstaff` method

```
enterstaff(String msg)...
```

and check if `msg` is not `null` before calling method

```
if ( null != msg && !msg.trim().equals(""))
{
   enterstaff(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just changed the name of the from staff to user. Now there is no exception and everything is working fine.